# Why I can not seek .ts file format video in Exo Player?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using Exo player in my application and it works absolutely fine for the .mp4 videos, I mean the controller of the player automatically detects the length of the video and there is a timeline by which I can seek. But when I pass the url of a .ts file it just play it without showing any duration and I can not even seek this file.

Answer (score 0):

ExoPlayer does not support seeking in media where the only method for performing accurate seek operations is for the player to scan and index the entire file. ExoPlayer considers such files as unseekable. Most modern media container formats include metadata for seeking (e.g., a sample index), have a well defined seek algorithm.
If you require seeking but have unseekable media, I suggest converting your content to use a more appropriate container format.

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me one more thing why video view in android get hang while playing file from urls multiple times.

Comment: Please upvote my answer if you like. Please attach your query with an example.